# React, unable to load img src dynamically

Tags: reactjs, image

I am having a heck of a time trying to load dynamic images while mapping in the return statement. If the image is static, no probablems.

This works:

```
src={require('../../assets/user-images/image-anne.jpg')}
```

However, I am mapping through a list of comments and need to display the images dynamically from the path given in the image path of the props.

The image prop looks like:

```
‘./assets/user-image/image-anne.jpg’
```

So I tried the following but this does not work:

```
src={require(`../.${image}`)}
```

I get the following:

“Cannot find module './../assets/user-images/image-anne.jpg”

I also try just using {image} but it doesn’t seem to know to look for the assets folder under src.

I am trying to load the images in a component under src/components/feedbackList

The images are in src/assets/user-images

If I go directly for the assets folder is gives me the standard "/assets falls outside of the /src directory."

Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: Why not `require` / `import` the image in the parent component and pass the resolved value as a prop, eg `import imageAnne from "./assets/user-image/image-anne.jpg"` and `<YourComponent image={imageAnne}>`

Comment: Thanks @Phil. That would be great if I could import the images but unfortunately that won't work since I am having to map through the list of comments and dynamically get the images.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code for dynamically changing `img` src

```
const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState('');

const loadImage = () => {
  // Update the image source dynamically
  setImageSrc('path/to/your/image.jpg');
};
  // Pass the state to img src
<img src={imageSrc} alt='image'/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Lokkesh. While this didn't work for me it did set on on the path to what did work.

I tried your first method but it seems to be looking for a module:

  Can’t find module ‘'../../assets/user-image/image-anne.jpg’

The second method does the same.

The only thing that worked was to separate the image name from the path:

let imageName = image.slice(image.lastIndexOf('/'));

Then include the imgName variable with the path:

src={require(`../../assets/user-images${imageName}`)}

It also doesn't work with .require. That had to be removed for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tips to able to load image.

1. See the Path is correct or not using import.
2. Console.log of path and Check it.

```js
let propUrl = "./assets/user-image/image-anne.jpg";

let url = "../."+ propUrl;

console.log(url)
```

3. If not working above the tips then use this one.

   `src={require("../." + image).default}`

Comment: Thanks @Ashish. Unfortunately using state didn't work off the bat as it does to many re-renders, as it's being used in map. I can't set the state in a useEffect since the state would have to be set from within the map.

Comment: @Chris .  Then, try this, it will work `src={image? require(`../.${image}`) : ' ' }`, when the image path is stored in 'Image' state then 'Image' will appear and it will work fine.